# How to reuse jest mock of react-router's useHistory

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jestjs

I am mocking the `useHistory` of `react-router-dom` in my test like this:

```js
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({
    length: 13,
    push: jest.fn(),
    block: jest.fn(),
    createHref: jest.fn(),
    go: jest.fn(),
    goBack: jest.fn(),
    goForward: jest.fn(),
    liten: jest.fn(),
    replace: jest.fn(),
    action: "REPLACE",
    location: null
  })
}));
```

This works perfectly fine in a single test, but I need this for basically every single test and I don't want to copy it every single time.

How can I reuse this mock? I've tried the obvious, moving it to a different file and exporting a function that creates the mock:

`export default () => jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({...})`

However, importing it and calling the function to create the mock results in an error.

```
import useHistoryMock from "../../../testUtils/hooks/useHistory";
useHistoryMock()
```

My component implementation then throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`, which it doesn't if I define the mock in the test file itself.

What is a convenient way to reuse the mock? I am using typescript so preferably I would not want to break any compiler rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the `__mocks__` folder 
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how to write `__mocks__/react-router-dom` properly ?